# Add Date Range Validation To Saturn-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, daterangepicker

What I want to do is that end date (90 days later since begin date) is decided automatically when I click begin date, not click both begin date and end date.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput formControlName="orderDate" [satDatepicker]="orderdate" autocomplete="off" readonly
                      placeholder="Order Date" />
      <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="orderdate"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
      <sat-datepicker #orderdate [rangeMode]="true">
      </sat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried capturing the beginDate through onDateChange event but the event gets fired only when both end date and begin date are selected. Is there any way where i can only get the begin date first so that I can add [max] validation for end date?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `setBeginDateSelected` in `ngOnInit`. This was the only way I was able to catch the begin date selected event.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.orderdate.setBeginDateSelected = (beginDate => {
      console.log(beginDate);
   });
}
```